# ERROR INICIAR APLICACIÓN CON SPRING JPA AL REALIZAR UN TEST

Tags: java, spring, jpa

He realizado el siguiente test sobre la entidad usuario.
Pero al iniciar la aplicación me da problemas.

```
@DataJpaTest
class UserTest {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;
    

    // Save user operation
    @Test
    void saveUser() {

        User user = User.builder().nick("userExample01").password("@ex4mp3").email("userExample@example.es")
                .state(UserState.Conectado).build();

        User savedUser = userRepository.save(user);

        Assertions.assertThat(savedUser).isNotNull();
        Assertions.assertThat(savedUser.getId()).isGreaterThan(0);
    }

    // Get all users operation
    @Test
    void getAllUsers() {

        User user = User.builder().nick("userExample01").password("@ex4mp3").email("userExample@example.es")
                .state(UserState.Conectado).build();

        User user2 = User.builder().nick("userExample02").password("sdf2A3").email("userExample2@example.es")
                .state(UserState.Desactivado).build();

        userRepository.save(user);
        userRepository.save(user2);

        List<User> userList = userRepository.findAll();

        assertThat(userList).isNotNull();
        assertThat(userList.size()).isEqualTo(2);

    }

    // Get users by id
    @Test
    void getUserById() {
        User user = User.builder().nick("userExample01").password("@ex4mp3").email("userExample@example.es")
                .state(UserState.Conectado).build();

        userRepository.save(user);

        User userIdDB = userRepository.findById(user.getId());

        assertThat(userIdDB).isNotNull();

    }

    // Get users by nick
    @Test
    void getUserByNick() {
        User user = User.builder().nick("userExample01").password("@ex4mp3").email("userExample@example.es")
                .state(UserState.Conectado).build();

        userRepository.save(user);

        User userNickDB = userRepository.findByNick(user.getNick());

        assertThat(userNickDB).isNotNull();

    }

    // Get users by state 
    @Test
    void getUserByState() {
        User user = User.builder().nick("userExample01").password("@ex4mp3").email("userExample@example.es")
                .state(UserState.Conectado).build();
        
        userRepository.save(user);
        
        List<User> users = userRepository.findByState(UserState.Conectado);
        assertThat(users).containsOnly(user);
    }
    
    //Update User
    @Test
    void updateUserById(){
        User user = User.builder()
                .nick("userExample01")
                .password("@ex4mp3")
                .email("userExample@example.es")
                .state(UserState.Conectado)
                .build();
        
        userRepository.save(user);
        
        User savedUser = userRepository.findById(user.getId());
        
            savedUser.setNick("ramgarcia");
            savedUser.setEmail("ram@gmail.com");
            savedUser.setPassword("ads23d");
            savedUser.setState(UserState.Conectado);
            
        User updateUser = userRepository.save(savedUser);
        
        assertThat(updateUser.getNick()).isEqualTo("ramgarcia");
        assertThat(updateUser.getEmail()).isEqualTo("ram@gmail.com");
        assertThat(updateUser.getPassword()).isEqualTo("ads23d");
        assertThat(updateUser.getState()).isEqualTo(UserState.Conectado);
    }
    
    //Delete User
    @Test
    void DeleteUser() {
        User user = User.builder()
                .nick("userExample01")
                .password("@ex4mp3")
                .email("userExample@example.es")
                .state(UserState.Conectado)
                .build();
        
        userRepository.save(user);
        
        userRepository.deleteById(user.getId());
        
        Optional<User> userOptional = Optional.ofNullable(userRepository.findById(user.getId()));
        assertThat(userOptional).isEmpty();
    }
}
```

Los test son correctos, no me da ningun error, el problema viene cuando intento iniciar  la aplicación, sin tener el test funciona e inicia correctamente al tener el test me da error como si no detectase el application.properties ya que me dice que no detecta el puerto ni la url a la base de datos. En cambio si elimino la clase donde realizo los test
me inicia sin problemas, porque puede ser esto.